# My arrays are not showing the proper value when calling my objects

Tags: javascript

So I have a school,teacher, student OO Js assignment. I have it working its just that When I send the "students" to detention or a classroom its not showing the proper value in the array.

```
//create a constructor for a school that has all teachers and students
function school(principal,teacher,student,classroom,detention){
    this.principal = principal,
    this.teacher = teacher,
    this.student = [],
    this.classroom = [],
    this.detention = []
}
//create a constructor for teachers and students 
//link them all together
function teacher(admin,name){
    school.call(this)
    this.admin = admin
    this.name = name
    admin = true
}



function student(fname,lname,year,average){
    teacher.call(this);

    this.fname = fname,
    this.lname = lname,
    this.year = year,
    this.average = average
}


teacher.prototype = Object.create(school.prototype);
//teacher can send students to class
teacher.prototype.learn = function(student){
    this.classroom.unshift(student)
}
//be able to move students to detention
teacher.prototype.punish = function(student){
    this.detention.push(student)
} 

//be able to view full details of each student.
student.prototype = Object.create(teacher.prototype)
student.prototype.fullDetails = function(){
    return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname + " is in " + this.year + 'th' + ' grade and his average is ' + this.average;
}


var mr_feeney = new teacher(true,"Mr.Feeney")
var corey = new student("corey","mathews",10,88)
var shaun = new student("shaun","hunter",10,43)
var topa = new student("topanga","lawrence",10,43)
mr_feeney.learn();
shaun.learn();
corey.learn();
topa.learn();


//IMPORTANT: arrays not showing proper values in the console log
```

Im still pretty new to JavaScript so and im not returning any errors in the console. I cant seem to pinpoint what exactly is missing or wrong from this code.

I understand the hierarchy of my code doesnt make sense. The purpose of the assignment was to be able to send students to a classroom array or detention array.

Comment: It's customary to write classes using title-case, e.g. `Teacher`, `Student`, and `School`.

Comment: can you show us what arrays you're logging, what their values are what you want them to be?

Comment: Your hierarchy makes no sense. How is a teacher a school? And how is a student a teacher? Also, why are you modifying an argument local to the constructor?

Comment: And for that matter how is a student a teacher?

Comment: Upvoted for the effort in OOP as a beginner programmer, but this code definitely has some issues.

Comment: Don't you think `Student` can't be a `Teacher`, in most cases? Shouldn't you consider creating a `Person` class and make `Student` and `Teacher` inherit from it. And `School` can contain multiple `Teacher` and `Student`objects. Also, no `Person` should be inheriting `School`.

Comment: yes the code does have some issues but what I am trying to do is send students into the detention and classroom arrays. @sauntimo I want the values to be whomever I choose to put in those arrays